# is there a way to do side-by-side literalinclude in sphinx python documentation?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am creating sphinx documentation for a python library I have written.

I want to show the text of two files side by side. Currently, I have them shown as a single image:

[image]

but if a user wants to copy and paste this information they can't.

So I am now converting these to inline references using `.. literalinclude::` directive

which looks like this:

[image]

is there any way I can somehow put in another file side by side with the current one?

Comment: panels was the answer